# From one array create another array

Tags: javascript

For example I have this JSON data:

```
const data = [
{
  title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
  sku: 'DD1391-100',
  size: '9 US',
},
{
  title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
  sku: 'DD1391-100',
  size: '10 US',
},
{
  title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
  sku: 'DD1391-100',
  size: '11 US',
},
]
```

How to create another array like:

```
const data = [
{
  title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
  sku: 'DD1391-100',
  size: '9 US, 10 US, 11 US'
}

]
```

I'm new in JS, trying to learn it )

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? BTW, this does not appear to be JSON, which is a string; but an array of objects.

Comment: Make an array of all the sizes. Then you can use `sizes.join(', ')` to create the comma-separated string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Do you want an array `['9 US', '10 US', '11 US']` or a list `'9 US, 10 US, 11 US'`

Comment: asking on stack overflow without an attempt is not what I'd call `trying to learn it` :p

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create a new array by aggregating the sizes for each unique combination of `title` and `sku`

- Create a map to store aggregated data
- Iterate over the original data
- Generate a unique key based on `title` and `sku`
- Check if the key exists in the map
- Append the size to the existing entry
- Create a new entry in the map
- Convert the map values to an array

```js
const originalData = [
  {
    title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
    sku: 'DD1391-100',
    size: '9 US',
  },
  {
    title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
    sku: 'DD1391-100',
    size: '10 US',
  },
  {
    title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
    sku: 'DD1391-100',
    size: '11 US',
  },
];

const aggregatedMap = new Map();

originalData.forEach((item) => {
  const key = `${item.title}-${item.sku}`;

  if (aggregatedMap.has(key)) {
    aggregatedMap.get(key).size += `, ${item.size}`;
  } else {
    aggregatedMap.set(key, { title: item.title, sku: item.sku, size: item.size });
  }
});

//result
const newData = Array.from(aggregatedMap.values());

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group by two keys and map the result by getting the wanted property from the group.

```js
const
    data = [{ title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda', sku: 'DD1391-100', size: '9 US' }, { title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda', sku: 'DD1391-100', size: '10 US' }, { title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda', sku: 'DD1391-100', size: '11 US' }],
    keys = ['title', 'sku'],
    result = Object
        .values(Object.groupBy(data, o => keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|')))
        .map(a => ({ ...a[0], size: a.map(({ size }) => size).join(', ') }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note: `Object.groupBy` is a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping/), already [implemented](https://caniuse.com/?search=Object.groupby) by all major vendors.

Comment: Didn't know groupBy was online already, cool!

Answer (score -2):

```js
const data = [{
    title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
    sku: 'DD1391-100',
    size: '9 US',
  },
  {
    title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
    sku: 'DD1391-100',
    size: '10 US',
  },
  {
    title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
    sku: 'DD1391-100',
    size: '11 US',
  },
]

sizeList = []

for (x of data) {
  sizeList.push(x['size'])
}

console.log({
  title: 'Nike Dunk Low Panda',
  sku: 'DD1391-100',
  size: sizeList
})
```

Comment: Please explain your code.